# Migrating dual boot OS from HDD to SSD

Tags: migration

I have a 1 tb HDD Win10+ Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot. I want to clone only the c: partition of my HDD, i.e, the partition responsible for boot to the new 240 GB SSD  . Without harming my Linux grub .

Is it possible to do. I have already read posts where they clone the whole HDD but i only want to clone the boot partition of my HDD.

Comment: UEFI install with gpt partitioning? Bit more difficult as with gpt there are unique GUID in primary partition table, partition and backup partition table. They must stay in sync or issues. And you must have unique UUIDs, so cannot just clone. With Ubuntu new install often easier and restore from your normal backup. But cloning Windows may be an issue. Most clone tools assume restore to same drive or new empty drive of same size, but not still having old drive, so no duplicate issues.Clone HDD to SSD with Macrium Reflect
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2306106&p=13406157#post13406157